# Better term than "hardcoded" for end-user documentation

Tags: single-word-requests

The term "hardcoded" refers to configuration that's imbedded in a program's code. To a programmer, it may have a negative connotation (if it is a bad design decision) and to a non-technical user, the term is probably too jargony.

For example, suppose Microsoft Word came with some templates hardcoded into the application. Users can use the hardcoded templates, but they can't modify them. These templates are tied to the version of Word installed too.

In end-user documentation, is there a better way to describe these templates than using the term "hardcoded templates"?

Comment: "default"?  ....

Comment: In the example, I would think "default" would refer to the template that would be used automatically when you create a new document. What I mean is if the user could chose between multiple "hardcoded templates", so it's not really a default (although the default template would be a "hardcoded template").

Comment: A ***fixed*** value?

Comment: Is the thing you're describing like a document template (which IMO is nothing like configuration), or like a scalar value, or like something else? It has a bearing on the answer, and I have no idea what _type_ of thing you're discussing.

Comment: The issue that caused me to post this question was related to documentation for laboratory software. Users have to enter to samples under specific "projects". Some of these projects are part of the application and can be used but not modified.

Comment: Does a project have state in itself, or is it just a label? That is, would you expect one to be editable, or perhaps just creatable/deletable?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the main feature seems to be that a template can't be modified or changed, here are some synonyms for **unchangeable**

[fixed](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fixed)

> predetermined and not able to be changed

which suggested another one

[predetermined](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predetermine#predetermine__3)

> established or decided in advance

speaking of which...

[preset](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/preset) (or *pre-set* according to MS Word)

> set or adjust (something) in advance of its use

and last but hopefully not the least

[prearranged](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/prearranged?searchDictCode=english)

> arranged beforehand, in advance

Note: I've adjusted dictionary definitions of *preset* and *predetermined* as verbs, because the dictionary stated that in participle form these can be used as adjectives

Comment: "preset" is the usual one in use, such as "preset styles/templates" in Word.

Comment: Preset is *close* but it doesn't convey the fact that in this case the user can't modify the object. Fixed is more accurate, but might not make immediate sense to some users (e.g. "fixed template? As opposed to a broken one?") Preset/fixed is what I want to convey, but using the slash feels sloppy.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, and it's strange how it uses the word preset(s), and yet when you try to write it in a document it corrects it to *pre-set* with a hyphen :-). Maybe a BrE/AmE variation... Or the matter of type of word - verb/noun/adjective...

Comment: In consultation with others writers in the office, we landed on "preset". This seemed to be the easiest to understand on its own.

Comment: @Scribblemacher - I'm glad you have a solution :-) . Best of luck with the software!

Comment: Yes, these are all synonyms, but only _fixed_ conveys the sense of immutability.  _Presets_ on your radio can be changed. _Prearranged and predetermined_ are more applicable for plans than for artifacts.

Comment: "factory preset" conveys that they can't be adjusted by the user.  Typically (but not necessarily) these are accompanied by "user presets" which can.

Answer (score 11):

Given that the **projects** you're talking about don't sound significantly like either document templates or configuration to me, I'd probably use *built-in*:

> A **sample** must be associated with a **project**. The built-in projects *X*, *Y* and *Z* cannot be altered, but you may also create other projects of your own.

---

In this context, I don't like *preset*, because that suggests a *collection of settings grouped for convenience* (equalizer presets, encoder presets, etc.). Settings are things that control or modify the operation of some process, and it isn't clear these projects have behaviour or internal state in this sense.

Answer (score 5):

Consider *static*, which is often contrasted with *dynamic.*

From [Webopedia's definition:](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/static.html)

> **static** (adj.) Generally refers to elements of the Internet or computer programming that are fixed and not capable of action or change. The opposite of static is dynamic.

Comment: _Static_ seems less clear and more jargon-y than the original "hardcoded".

Answer (score 3):

> In end-user documentation, is there a better way to describe these templates than using the term "hardcoded templates"?

Two scenari :

- You want to sell your product;
  Then you should call them *presets* as in @Lucky answer.
- You want to explain problems/poor or special design;
  Then you can call them **not configurable**.

Comment: "not configurable" is a great solution for explaining poor design. When writing user documentation for software designed without UX in mind can be quite a challenge

Answer (score 3):

If you want to emphasize the fact that they "users can't modify them", then you could say that those templates are *unmodifiable*.

On the other hand, if you want to emphasize the fact that they come pre-packaged with Microsoft Word, then call them *built-in* templates.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the term "baked-in" used in software development. It carries the same meaning as hard-coded but implies it was done with good reason and not due to some error or omission. Some examples [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bake). Look under the heading 'Phrasal Verbs'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you provide an example or reference to support your answer, especially since this is industry-specific jargon?

Comment: I think "baked-in" might not translate or be too idiomatic for non-native speakers, since it's somewhat a cooking metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

I would call those templates "read only", meaning that you cannot write/modify them.  That is a phrase that non-technical people can understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would express it with :" ...choose from default settings/values ...", but generally it depends on your sentence, because right know we are shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

[The designs of] these templates are set in (name of?) the program, and can't be modified.

This or similar seems to me clear and layperson-friendly.