# Synynom for "Plug-and-Play"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm writing a companion document to a spreadsheet my company provides to clients. The spreadsheet consists of columns that correlate to the database, and, therefore, cannot be changed, added to, or otherwise updated.

I want to explain—in a non-techie way—that the programming itself is, well, plug-and-play. We install it and the data/functionality is what it is.

Is there a single word or simple phrase that accomplishes this? I'm worried the phrase "plug-and-play" might be a little too specific/rare for quite a bit of our clientele.

Here's the opening sentence, if it helps at all:

> The products module is a «something» e-commerce solution.

**Edit:**
There seems to be a bit of confusion. Here's a little more context:
We provide a product upload via a pre-set spreadsheet. The spreadsheet itself does not update.

Comment: Plug-and-play means that you plug it in and it works without any hassle or additional configuration, which isn't really how you're using it here. It sounds like you might want to use [proprietary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proprietary).

Comment: Erm... I'd have assumed ***Plug-and-Play*** was specifically *coined* in order to be understood by "non-techie" people (true techies would probably call it ***hot-swappable***).

Comment: @SomethingDark "Proprietary" doesn't work in this context. The entire system is proprietary. The module itself is pre-built, but I don't really want to say __that__ as it might connote that it's not worth paying for.

Comment: **Non-configurable** would be the most accurate, although hardly marketable. **Preconfigured** is far more consumer-friendly and would convince most customers to not bother trying to mess with the backend, but implies that the software can be configured. **Black box** would also work as long as you don't mind sounding slightly ominous.

Comment: @SomethingDark I like "preconfigured". Can you post that as an answer? I'm not going to select one until tomorrow, but I think that may be the winner regardless.

Comment: Why not *automatic*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Eh, those terms mean different things. Hot-swappable means hardware that can be replaced without powering down the system, as is common for hard drives in servers for example. Plug-and-play was originally coined to describe hardware that doesn't need special configuration, like dip switches to set the base memory address of an ISA card, as was the norm at the time.

Comment: 'Fire and Forget' was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: "Plug-and-play" is most definitely the *wrong* term to use. Can you perhaps add some other terms that describe what this thing does?

Comment: Which is it: you don't want to call it "pre-built" or "proprietary"... or neither? *Proprietary* would tell me everything you just did: it (only) works as we say it does, you cannot change it and it costs Money. IMO, *plug-and-play* would mean exactly what you need it to mean, to a non-techie. **Proprietary** is what it is though. --Is *appled* a word yet? Perhaps, *applefied*...

Comment: @Mazura The issue with "pre-built" is, to me, because it's already built, why should I pay for it? This is a product we sell, and it does take some time (and time is money) to set up, but that wording, along with "drop-in" and similar, make it seem like it takes no time at all. As for "proprietary", yes, it is. But we make many other proprietary, customizable modules. The difference with this one is the default complexity makes it fiscally...challenging to edit. A binary flag here or there can be done, but beyond that, it's really not possible.

Comment: Related: [Better term than 'hardcoded' for end user documentation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241409/better-term-than-hardcoded-for-end-user-documentation/241529)

Comment: You're having trouble thinking outside the common lexicon for your techie world.  Plug-and-play, to the rest of us, means slap-it-in-and-don't-worry.  In your mind, picture sitting your grandmother down and explaining it to her.

Comment: If it takes time to setup then it's *not* P&P, it's **tailored to suit**.

Comment: I hope that you are " locking down" the spreadsheet to prevent the customer from altering columns or fiddling with the data.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock My mother asked the same thing. I wish we could, but because we can't guarantee what our end-users are using, we can't do that. **Or**, and this has happened, they'll take it as a guideline and just make a new file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to convince the users that the spreadsheet does not need to be altered if you refer to it as **preconfigured**.

> [preconfigure](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preconfigure) (v) - Configure in advance

Note that this will not stop some users from attempting to alter the spreadsheet anyway, as the word may suggest some degree of reconfigurability, but it should be enough to satisfy the majority of your userbase.

Comment: In the end, this is the most accurate definition and is most broadly understood.

Answer (score 8):

This is a **turnkey solution.**

From [The Free Dictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/turnkey)

> **turn·key**
>
> adj.
>
> 1. Supplied, installed, or purchased in a condition ready for immediate use, occupation, or operation: a turnkey computer system; a turnkey housing project.
> 2. Of or relating to something supplied, installed, or purchased in this manner: a turnkey agreement.

A turnkey product is provided ready to use, and is not customized to suit the customer's needs.

Comment: I looked up the definition of turnkey initially. The definitions [I found](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/turnkey) were not ideal, as they included an overtone of "customized". I also asked my project manager, and she said, "No."

Comment: @VampDuc "Turnkey" seems to match your description, though.  The allusion is to, say, a new house where you're handed a key and when you "turn the key" and walk in the furniture is all there, the refrigerator is already stocked, the beds are made, etc -- nothing needs to be done on the customer's part to make the product ready.  I'm guessing your problem with the term is that it does not *completely* describe your product, however, in terms of the non-configurability of it.  Ie, the furniture is nailed to the floor and cannot be moved if the occupant so wishes.

Comment: @HotLicks I understand, but there's a second definition which is closer to someone coming in, figuring out what you need, building it, _then_ handing you the key. The issue is the ambiguity in the term itself. It can mean both **pre-built** and **built-to-suit**.

Comment: Yeah, it's a question of whether it's a tract home or custom built.

Answer (score 2):

Plug-and-play carries with it a lot of meaning that you're not using, here. It connotes ease-of-installation and immediate, **drop-in**, **out of the box** functionality.

But plug-and-play absolutely does not mean "unconfigurable," which appears to be the main thing you're trying to convey here.

Still, I think **drop in** and **out of the box** warrant consideration. Both of these convey that the spreadsheet/product does not need to be customized or configured, but can be easily put into place and immediately used to full effect.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest ***ready-to-use***. It is easy to understand for a non-techie also.

You can check examples [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22ready-made%20software%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=jHdaVcToJ42pyAS6-YG4Ag#q=%22ready-to-use%20solution%22%20e-commerce&start=0) about how it is used.

---

Another option is ***ready-made***. (as in *ready-made software* vs. *bespoke software*)

You can check examples [here](https://www.google.ca/search?q=ready-made%20software&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=HX1aVdXWBsSTyAT2zoG4Ag#q=%22ready-made%20software%22).

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was *black box*, as you're describing a closed module to which a limited interface is provided. This is similar to the design of the *black box* device found in aircraft and commonly mentioned in news articles, therefore being familiar to even your least-technical readers.

I might also call such a thing *self-contained*, or *isolated*, or *partitioned*.

Answer (score 1):

*Maintenance free* may also work, as you say that this spreadsheet updates automatically.

Answer (score 1):

"Plug-and-Play", as defined by the computer industry standard protocol, does not mean "preconfigured" or "ready-to-use", it means "self-configuring" (albeit with the assistance of the system with which the device interoperates).

Answer (score 0):

I dont think plug and play is appropriate here. I would suggest **"inextensible"** as an alternative. It appears to be closer to your meaning.

Plug and play generally implies that something works without any configuration or setup, literally just having to plug in some kind of device. That doesnt seem to be the case here rather you have a product that cannot be changed or extended.